# Observable: What's the difference between subscribing data in a component and in a service?

Tags: angular, observable

Is there any significant difference between subscribing an observable in a component, or subscribing it in the service with a callback as a parameter?

Component

```
constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
     this.dataService.getData()
     .subscribe(users => {
      this.user = users;
      console.log(this.user);
     });
```

Service

```
getData() {    
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json())
       }
```

VS

Component

```
constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.getData( callback => {
      this.user = this.dataService.user;
    });
```

Service:

```
 getData(callback: (receiver: User) => void) {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.user = users;
        callback(this.user);
        console.log(this.user);
      });
  }
```

The result is identical, so I don't quite get the difference, besides a bit more complex sintax. Which is the best aproach?

Comment: Just as a side note, it common practice to put as little as possible inside the constructor. Constructors are pure JS and fire before Angular has initialized its change detection fully and the DOM is ready.

Comment: yes, this was for testing only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my understanding, It's not considered a best practice to subscribe in a service. When you subscribe to an observable (particularly a hot observable, since they don't complete) it creates a subscription. If you do not unsubscribe from the subscriptions, with the Async pipe or manually, then it can create memory leaks that will degrade your application's performance. But hiding the subscription also prevents the observable from being chained to other observables to create more "reactive" applications.

In your example above example, I would *never* have that subscribes in the service and sets a public property for angular to watch. Also, it could potentially lead to change detection issues along with other issues including maintainability.

Comment: but, like ViVek explained, when the app gets bigger, we'll get the beneffits because the subscription is global, right?

Comment: No, that is not the case, in fact, it's the opposite. Because your application won't be able to take advantage of angulars OnPush change detection and instead will have to watch the users property for changes. The larger your application becomes the worse it will be.

Comment: if you want to share that data without having to make multiple HTTP requests you should look into how to share observable responses such as replay subjects, publish etc.

Comment: ok, that makes sense; so in your point of view the components subscribe, always?

Comment: Correct, there are always exceptions to the rules but in this case, I've never come across a situation where I would need to subscribe in a service. When I have, it's been a good sign that I need to go back and refactor my code, which has always resulted with me finding a better way to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Comment: @theOriginalJosh Much better answer than the accepted answer. Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can write service anyhwere you want , but it depends on some standard way and requirements

Just like MVC architecture , where you can do all the thing on same page but you still do it in different module , just to make it more readable and make it reliable

This is the same thing with Angular2.

By writing the service in different file , you can make that service global or shareable by multiple component , that you can't do if you are writing in component.

> If you want my opinion , make separate file for service and always
>   write your code in it , no matter if it has only one service ( api /
>   function ) , but in future when application gets bigger , you will see
>   the benefits then.
>
> Always subscribe from the component and never from the service

For More Detail : **[Please Read](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#architecture-overview)**

Comment: so the "best" aproach is the first one, right? Since the the subscribe method has a callback itself?

Comment: ok, so if the app is small, I'go with the first aproach, otherwise, i'll go with the second, is that your point?

Comment: If you want my opinion , make separate file for service and always write your code in it , no matter if it has only one service ( api / function ) , but in future when application gets bigger , you will see the benefits then | you should create separate file always.

Comment: @Mellville , also go through the link I have updated in answer, and specifically https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services , you will get the deep details about the service

Answer (score 1):

It's just an architectural style. The best approach is to subscribe from the component, as you sometimes may face a scenario to do something with your component's members as the service returns.

For instance, you may want to close a modal that's a part of the component, as the service returns.

If you subscribe in the service,
you'll not have access to the modal, which is a part of the component, unless you pass a reference explicitly, which obviously is not an elegant way.

If you subscribe in the component,
you can do anything, you can do anything with the component's members, before / after doing something with the data.

Also, a good analogy would be, subscribing to a food delivery service.

Which option would you prefer?

Give your number to the restaurant and ask them to call you as soon as the food is ready, or getting delivered it at your door as the food becomes ready?

Comment: @Mellville, another point to major advantage subscribe in component is that you can subscribe to several observables (using forkJoin, e.g.  or switchMap) from serveral services in a component. If you subscribe in a service you lost all the advantages operators Rxjs offer you

Answer (score 1):

Where to subscribe differs from architecture to architecture, or the problem you are trying to solve. Many applications store their data in ngrx store and subscribe to store's reducer for getting the data. In this case service will subscribe to http call and dispatch the data in store. Component will get data from store.

Lets say, you have 4 components in a view all showing list of countries. If one of them re fetch list of countries, you want all 4 to have the updated response. What you will do? you will subscribe to http call in service and put the data in your behavior subject or subject.

If you want to subscribe it in template, you can't subscribe it in service until you are subscribing the behavior subject's observable to which you will push the data.

If you are not using state management via ngrx or behavior subject or any other state sharing thing, you can then subscribe in component.

In case of non continuous observables like http calls unsubscribing is not required, its mainly required in continuous observable like if you are having an observable on a event.